# JSON Data loading into Redshift Table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to load JSON Data into Redshift Table. Below is the sample code, Table structure and JSON Data.

I have gone through many post in this site and AWS. However, my issue is not yet resolved.

JSON data is below, that I copied the below data in `test.json` and uploaded in S3...

```
{backslash: "a",newline: "ab",tab: "dd"}
```

Table structure is as below

```
create table escapes (backslash varchar(25), newline varchar(35), tab 
varchar(35));
```

Copy command is as below

```
copy escapes  from 's3://dev/test.json'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=******;aws_secret_access_key=$$$$$'
format as JSON 'auto';
```

However it throws the below error

> Amazon Invalid operation: Load into table 'escapes' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.;
>   1 statement failed.
>
> In the 'stl_load_errors' table , the error reason is as below  "Invalid value."

Comment: If its not `typo`, I think its data format issue. Given JSON is not valid. `{ backslash: "a", newline: "ab", tab: "dd" }` ideally it should be `{ "backslash": "a","newline": "ab", "tab": "dd" }`

Comment: I have already tired with the data as  { "backslash": "a", "newline": "ab", "tab": "dd" }. It didn't work. That's the reason I edited the JSON data as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @cloudguru I tried its working. share your actual data in test.json

Comment: @ iammehrabalam, Is there any configuration needs to be defined in the Redshift Table. My Table is defined as mentioned in the Original Question. Since the Data loading didn't work with Actual Data , I created a Simple JSON file to test with the above sample data and trying with copy command...

Comment: Sorry Friends.. It was my JSON file which has issue. I am using windows Notepad++.. There was some special character which I could not visualize.

Comment: I found this article on the topic: https://sonra.io/2019/04/24/working-with-json-in-redshift-options-limitations-and-alternatives/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like issue is with your JSON data. Ideally it should be-

```
{
 "backslash": "a",
 "newline": "ab",
 "tab": "dd"
}
```

I hope this should resolve your issue, but if not, update your question and I could reattempt the answer.